# Emacs, ESS, R -How did i do this?

Tags: emacs, r, ess

http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/F-p2qK3itxJsgj1tLLGsow?feat=directlink

If you look at the picture, theres this usage bit from the R help files at the bottom in the minbuffer.

howd i do that? it somehow just appeared, maybe cos i mashed the keyboard trying to run the commands.
It disappeared when i restarted emacs:(

thanks

Answer (score 6):

There is a function `ess-r-args-show` that does this.

I'm not sure what the default keybindings are for it, but somehow I've ended up with this in one of my config files, which binds it to F2:

```
;; Show function argument completion while editing R code and interacting with
;; an inferior R process
(define-key ess-mode-map [f2] 'ess-r-args-show)
(define-key ess-mode-map [f3] 'ess-r-args-insert)
(define-key inferior-ess-mode-map [f2] 'ess-r-args-show)
(define-key inferior-ess-mode-map [f3] 'ess-r-args-insert)
```

I believe your current `*.R` buffer needs to be "tied" to a running ESS/R process.

Comment: By default `ess-r-args-show` should be activated whenever you press <kbd>(</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

There is an `ess-eldoc` package which would display the args whenever you are inside the parenthesis. To activate put:

```
(require 'ess-eldoc)
```

in your emacs after you load the `ess-site`.

[Edit]: ess-eldoc package does not exist anymore. Eldoc is activated by default in ESS.